# tensorflow-gpu error: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Trying to install tensorflow-gpu version 1.8.

Already installed NVIDIA,CUDA and cudnn.
I'm using windows 10 and python 3.
created an environment.

When trying:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.8
```

I get:

> Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.8   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/a8/4c96a2b4f88f5d6dfd70313ebf38de1fe4d49ba9bf2ef34dc12dd198ab9a/tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (0.2.0) Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.4.0 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (3.5.2) Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (0.32.1) Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (1.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.1.6 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (0.5.0) Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (0.7.1) Collecting tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 (from
>   tensorflow-gpu==1.8)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/a6/0ae6092b7542cfedba6b2a1c9b8dceaf278238c39484f3ba03b03f07803c/tensorboard-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (1.12.1) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (1.11.0) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.8)
>   (1.15.2) Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   protobuf>=3.4.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.8) (39.1.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.8) (0.9999999)
>   Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.8) (0.14.1) Requirement
>   already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.8) (2.6.8) Requirement
>   already satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in
>   c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
>   tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.8) (1.5.0)
>   ***Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'c:\users\sarit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow-1.11.0.dist-info\METADATA'***

Couldn't find a solution for that. Be happy to get some help

Comment: Are you trying the install in anaconda environment?

Comment: yes, i'm installing according to a guide and that's one of the requirements

Comment: if you are using anaconda environment, you would run in to problems using pip
Refer to [this guide](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/) to do the installation with conda!